# commands which dont exist refer to python instead of apt suggestion

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I had some issues when installing a newer version of python on my ubuntu installation. Having downloaded a few different versions i then changed some soft links including repointing python to the 3.8 version as well as pip to pip3.

Now my issue is that when ever i type something that normally I would get an apt suggestion for or expect to a command not found error i now get a python error

**Example from working VM which i didnt mess with**

```
ubuntu@vps-f116ed9f:/usr/bin$ wer

Command 'wer' not found, did you mean:

  command 'we' from deb xwpe (1.5.30a-2.1build3)
  command 'ner' from deb frog (0.15-1build2)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>

ubuntu@vps-f116ed9f:/usr/bin$ lskdflskdf
lskdflskdf: command not found
```

**Example from the VM i changed python and softlink**

```
myuser@myhost:/usr/bin$ wer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'


myuser@myhost:/usr/bin$ lkjsdfkljsdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

Does anyone know what i can do to fix it so that i will get apt suggestions or "command not found" messages again?

Comment: Undo your changes.

Comment: @MichaelHampton lol, sudo apt-get install  --reinstall command-not-found but truely, seems to nuked  the python installations

Answer (score 0):

Undo your changes. The suggested packages imply Ubuntu 20.04, but Focal already has a python3 package at 3.8. I do not know what you did to get in this state.

Find the deb package containing Python module apt_pkg, the python3 version.

```
apt-file search apt_pkg
```

[Reinstall apt_pkg](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588066/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-apt-pkg-appears-in-various-commands) to ensure Python apt bindings exist.

```
apt reinstall python3-apt
```